# Extra properties on Mongoose schema field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to add extra / custom attributes to the field in a Mongoose schema?  For example, note the `name:` attribute on the following fields:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({

    _id : { type: String, default: $.uuid.init },

    n   : { type: String, trim: true, name: 'name' },

    ac  : { type: Date, required: true, name: 'created' },
    au  : { type: Date, name: 'updated' },
    ad  : { type: Date, name: 'deleted' },
    am  : { type: String, ref: 'Member', required: true, name: 'member' }
});
```

We expect to have a large number of docs in our system and would like to conserve as much space as possible.  In this example, we have abbreviated the name of the fields (`n` vs `name`, etc.).  We would like to use the additional `name` field to hydrate a JSON object after a fetch.

Comment: In Mongoose, "hydration" means creating a Mongoose document _from_ a regular JS object, but you want it the other way around (create a JS object from a Mongoose document where `n` gets mapped to `name`)?

Comment: Correct.  Once the doc is pulled from the DB, we convert it to a JS object for passing around (persisting to redis, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You could create an instance method (which I called `toMappedObject`, but you're free to name it however you like) that could perform the conversion by checking the schema for each field to see if it has a `name` property:

```
schema.methods.toMappedObject = function() {
  let obj = this.toObject();

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(fieldName => {
    let field = schema.tree[fieldName];
    if (field.name) {
      obj[field.name] = obj[fieldName];
      delete obj[fieldName];
    }
  });

  return obj;
}

// Example usage:
let doc = new Model({...});
let obj = doc.toMappedObject();
```

Alternatively, you can configure your schema to automatically transform the output generated by [`toJSON`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toJSON), although it's much more implicit so easy to overlook in case issues pop up (I haven't tested this very well):

```
schema.set('toJSON', {
  transform : function(doc, obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(fieldName => {
      let field = doc.schema.tree[fieldName];
      if (field.name) {
        obj[field.name] = obj[fieldName];
        delete obj[fieldName];
      }
    });

    return obj;
  }
});

// Example usage:
let doc = new Model({...});
console.log('%j', doc); // will call `doc.toJSON()` implicitly
```